# Animate layer on animated UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm having trouble animating a layer on one of my views. I have googled the issue, but only find answers using `CATransaction` which assumes that I know the `fromValue` and `toValue` of its bounds. I have a view in a `tableHeader` that resizes itself when clicked. This view is an ordinary `UIView` and animates just as expected in an `UIView.animate()`-block. This view has a `CAGradientLayer` as a sublayer, to give it a gradient backgroundcolor. When the view animates its height, the layer does not animate with it. The layer changes its bounds immediately when the animation starts.

To make sure the layer gets the right size overall (during init/loading/screen rotation etc.) I have been told to do this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = backgroundView.bounds
}
```

It gets the right size every time, but it never animates to it.

To do my view-animation, I do this:

```
self.someLabelHeightConstraint.constant = someHeight
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in                
    self?.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

which works perfectly, but I assume `layoutIfNeeded()` calls `layoutSubviews` at some point, which I assume will ruin any CALayer-animations I add into the block.

As you can see, I only change the constant of a constraint set on a view inside my view, so I actually don't know what the size of the actual header-view will be when the animation is completed. I could probably do some math to figure out what it'll be, but that seems unnecessary..

Are there no better ways to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are kludgy ways to update a sublayer's `frame` during an animation, but the most elegant solution is to let `UIKit` take care of this for you. Create a subclass `UIView` whose [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) is a `CAGradientLayer`. When the view is created, the `CAGradientLayer` will be created for you. And when you animate the view's frame, the gradient layer is animated gracefully for you.

```
@IBDesignable
public class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var startColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() } }
    @IBInspectable public var endColor:   UIColor = .black { didSet { updateColors() } }

    override open class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }

    override public init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        config()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        config()
    }

    private func config() {
        updateColors()
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer

        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }

}
```

Note, I've made this `@IBDesignable` so you can put it in a framework target and then use it in IB, but that's up to you. That's not required. The main issue is the overriding of `layerClass` so that UIKit takes care of the animation of the layer as it animates the view.

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! I'm not exactly sure why, though. What is happening? Does the original CALayer in a UIView have built-in logic for this, and you essentially made a UIView where the original CALayer is a CAGradientLayer, giving it all that magic? I initially thought this was the case, but when I tried to set self.layer = gradientLayer, I was told that self.layer was read-only. Your solution was brilliant.

Comment: Yeah, you can't change the layer after the fact with `self.layer = gradientLayer`, but rather specify `layerClass` so UIKit does both the original instantiation _and_ the animation. Once familiar with this technique, it's actually easier, but it's not exactly obvious, is it?

Comment: This is genius! Thanks

Comment: Does this also work with other layers? For example i have a layer with a dashed border that i want to animate like this.

Comment: @iVentis No, this isn’t going to work for `CAShapeLayer` because you need to update the `path`. Options include `CABasicAnimation` or `CADisplayLink` driven animation. The easiest option is to render the border within `draw(_:)` method (and use `contentMode` of `.redraw`) ... the stroking isn’t perfect mid animation, but if your animation is reasonably short, no one will notice. But, all of this is beyond the scope of this question and I’d suggest you post your own...

Comment: @Rob thanks for your quick answer! I solved it by animating the layer with the same animation options. https://medium.com/@maxcampolo/animating-uiview-sublayers-fa549e82cbbd

Comment: The reason why this solution works is because you changed the backing layer for UIView. And UIView (as the delegate of the backing layer) provides `action`s for the layer during UIKit animations. For sublayers of the backing layer, you can use `viewBackingLayer.action(forKey: "backgroundColor") as? CABasicAnimation` to get a such action. Then use this animation as a reference  for animation duration and timing function. Then add customized animations for sublayers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the actions of the `CALayer`

**Add this code**

```
gradientLayer.actions = ["position": NSNull(),"frame":NSNull(),"bounds":NSNull()]
```

Comment: What will this solve? Will it make my layer automatically work with the UIView.animate-code, or does it make my layer's own CATransaction-animation work alongside UIView.animate?