# can I use a Gradient color in Launch screen xcode

Tags: edit, xcode9, xcode-storyboard

I want to know if it's possible to use gradient colors in the launchscreen.storyboards if so where can I edit it. I'm not looking to add images because it can make the app to heavy but maybe a transition to change the gradient from a-colors to b-colors.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render gradients programmatically in a storyboard, you can generally define a [`UIView` subclass to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49885994/1271826), but you cannot use custom classes in the launch screen. You’ll have to use an image.

---

If your gradient is a simple vertical or horizontal gradient, and you’re really concerned about asset size, you can define a very narrow image and then add an image view with “scale to fill” content mode.

But these images are so small anyway, the amount of space saved will be negligible, so I’m not sure it’s worth worrying about.

Comment: I guess it was more about creating images for all devices and orientations but yeah you're right the images shouldn't be too big. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TyWatson - If you’re using storyboard and the image is a simple gradient, you can probably get away with a single image, set the image view to scale to fill, and you’re done.